# Convergence problem in probability for iid RVs

Tags: real-analysis, probability, analysis, probability-theory, convergence-divergence

Consider a sequence $X_1,X_2,...,$ of independent identically distributed random variables, and set $$Y_n=\frac{1}{n} \max_{1 \leq j \leq n}|X_j|, \ \ \   n\in \mathbb{N}.$$

Givenn $Y_n \to 0$ in probability, we are to show: $\lim_{x \to \infty} x\mathbb{P}(|X_1|> x) = 0$.

Here's my progress so far. I am unable to proceed beyond this.

For any given $\epsilon > 0$:

\begin{align*} 
\mathbb{P} (|Y_n| > \epsilon) = 1 - \mathbb{P}(|Y_n| \leq \epsilon) = 1 - \mathbb{P}(\max_{1 \leq j \leq n}|X_j| \leq n \epsilon) \\
= 1 - \mathbb{P}(\bigcap_{1 \leq j \leq n} \{|X_j| \leq n \epsilon \}) \\
= 1 - \displaystyle  \prod_{j=1}^{n}\mathbb{P}(|X_j| \leq n \epsilon)\\
= 1 - [\mathbb{P}(|X_1| \leq n \epsilon)]^{n}\\
= 1 - [1 - \mathbb{P}(|X_1| > n \epsilon)]^{n}
\end{align*}

The product is a consequence of independence and the final quantity follows from identical distributions.

I've considered using logs here or even the Bernoulli's inequality but neither seems to work.

Comment: You could alternatively assume $xP[|X_1|>x]$ does _not_ go to zero.  So there is a $\delta>0$ and a sequence of positive and increasing real numbers $\{x_i\}_{i=1}^{\infty}$ such that $\lim_{i\rightarrow\infty} x_i = \infty$ and $x_iP[|X_1|>x_i]\geq \delta$ for all $i$.  WLOG you can assume the $x_i$ values are positive integers.

Comment: $$\exp(-nP(|X_1|>n))\geqslant[1-P(|X_1|>n)]^n\to1$$

Answer (score 0):

You established that
$$
P(|Y_n|>\varepsilon)=1-[1-P(|X_1|>n\varepsilon)]^n.
$$
Since $P(|Y_n|>\varepsilon)\to0$ as $n\to\infty$, $[1-P(|X_1|>n\varepsilon)]^n\to1$ as $n\to\infty$. Hence, $P(|X_1|>n\varepsilon)\to0$ as $n\to\infty$. We know that
$$
(1-x/n)^n\to e^{-x}
$$
for $x\in\mathbb R$ as $n\to\infty$. Hence, $P(|X_1|>n\varepsilon)$ has to go to $0$ faster than $1/n$ (otherwise the limit cannot be equal to $1$). By setting $\varepsilon=1$, we obtain that $nP(|X_1|>n)\to0$ as $n\to\infty$.

Answer (score 0):

Resuming from your last equality : the term $[1 - \mathbb{P}(|X_1| > n \epsilon)]^{n}\to 1$ as $n\to +\infty$. So applying the logarithm, we get : $n \log (1 - \mathbb{P}(|X_1| > n \epsilon)) \to 0$. It implies that $\mathbb{P}(|X_1| > n \epsilon)=o(1)$ and by a Taylor expansion we have : $-n\mathbb{P}(|X_1| > n \epsilon)\to 0 $. Taking $\epsilon =1$ gives the result.